# Python create secret with tags in Google Secret manager

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I am using Google Cloud run for my applications.
I am storing all my secrets in Google Cloud Secret Manager.

To read secrets I do the following:

```
from google.cloud import secretmanager
import hashlib


def access_secret_version(secret_id, version_id="latest"):
    # Create the Secret Manager client.
    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()

    # Build the resource name of the secret version.
    PROJECT_ID = "xxxxx"
    name = f"projects/{PROJECT_ID}/secrets/{secret_id}/versions/{version_id}"

    # Access the secret version.
    response = client.access_secret_version(name=name)

    # Return the decoded payload.
    return response.payload.data.decode('UTF-8')


def secret_hash(secret_value):
    # return the sha224 hash of the secret value
    return hashlib.sha224(bytes(secret_value, "utf-8")).hexdigest()
```

To write secrets:

```
from google.cloud import secretmanager


def create_secret(secret_id):
    # Create the Secret Manager client.
    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()

    # Build the resource name of the parent project.
    PROJECT_ID = "xxxx"
    parent = f"projects/{PROJECT_ID}"

    # Build a dict of settings for the secret
    secret = {'replication': {'automatic': {}}}

    # Create the secret
    response = client.create_secret(secret_id=secret_id, parent=parent, secret=secret)

    # Print the new secret name.
    print(f'Created secret: {response.name}')
```

How can I create secrets with tags in Python?

Answer (score 1):

One method to determine if feature is available is to study the REST API. Secrets do not support tags.

- [Method: projects.secrets.create](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.secrets/create)
- [Resource: Secret](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.secrets#Secret)

Secrets support **labels**, **annotations** and **versionAliases**.

Depending on your use case, **versionAliases** might be work instead of tags.

> Optional. Mapping from version alias to version name.
>
> A version alias is a string with a maximum length of 63 characters and
> can contain uppercase and lowercase letters, numerals, and the hyphen
> (-) and underscore ('_') characters. An alias string must start with a
> letter and cannot be the string 'latest' or 'NEW'. No more than 50
> aliases can be assigned to a given secret.
>
> Version-Alias pairs will be viewable via secrets.get and modifiable
> via secrets.patch. At launch Access by Allias will only be supported
> on versions.get and versions.access.